# Update EditTextPreference title when other preference is pulsed in Android

Tags: android, preferences, edittextpreference

I've an Android application with a setting menu. I've some EditTextPreferences that when is changed a button in the UI changes too. Moreover, I would like to implemente a Preference that reset the values of all EditTextPreferences. Now I have:

**preference.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="custom_balizamiento"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="@string/balizamiento" >

  <EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/custom_event_1"
    android:key="custom_event_balizamiento_1"
    android:title="@string/custom_event_1" />

  <EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/custom_event_2"
    android:key="custom_event_balizamiento_2"
    android:title="@string/custom_event_2" />
</PreferenceScreen>
<Preference
        android:key="button_reset"
        android:summary="@string/pref_reset_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_reset" />
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
Preference buttonreset = (Preference) findPreference("button_reset");
    buttonreset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

            pref.edit().clear();
            pref.edit().commit();
            pref.edit().apply();
            updatePreference();
            pref.edit().commit();
            pref.edit().apply();
            return true;
        }
    });

public void updatePreference() {

    Map<String, ?> keys = pref.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().contains("custom_event")) {
            Preference auxpref = findPreference(entry.getKey());
            String newValue = pref
                    .getString(entry.getKey(), entry.getKey());
            auxpref.setTitle(newValue);

        }

    }

    pref.edit().commit();

}
```

When I pulse the reset prefence, nothing change. However, when I close the settings fragment and open it again the preference and the button in the UI changes to the default value. How can I update the button and the preference when I pulse the reset preference?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. I've changed the Listener code:

```
Preference buttonreset = (Preference) findPreference("button_reset");
buttonreset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

        pref.edit().clear().commit();
        pref.edit().apply();
        updatePreference();
        pref.edit().commit();
        pref.edit().apply();
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.layout.preferences, true);
        pref.edit().apply();

                return true;
            }
        });
```